# subdirectories (empty ones) are not pushed to git repo

Tags: git, github

I'm setting up the skeleton for my project, so I created some directories like this under my project root directory:

```
+src
  |
  +--- etc
  |     +--header.txt
  |
  +--- main
  |     |
  |     +--- java
  |     |
  |     +--- resources
  |
  +--- test
        |
        +--- java
        |
        +--- resources
```

I committed and push the changes but on my github repo web UI, I only see `src/etc`

`src/main` and `src/test` are not present!!!

Does `git` NOT allow pushing empty directories?
Is there any way to force this?

Thanks

Comment: See here: [How do I add an empty directory to a git repository](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository)

Answer (score 2):

Git does not track directories explicitly, but only tracks files. It therefore cannot track empty directories.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a dummy file in the empty directories you wish to push.  Add that file to your repo and the directories will come along for the ride...